# Customview inside viewpager in android not changing when nightmode is enabled

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

We are implementing the nightmode support for android with:

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(if(active) AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES else AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)`

However it works on normal layout files but we are experiencing issues with our customview. We implemented an abstract view which inflates the right view according to the implementation.

```
class DrivingModeDashboardView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null
    ) : BaseDrivingModeView(context, R.layout.view_driving_mode_dashboard, attrs) {
        override val speedAdviceView: SpeedAdviceImageView
            get() = adviceSpeed
        override val currentSpeedView: MaxSpeedTextView
            get() = currentSpeed
        override val maxSpeedView: AnimatedMaxSpeedView
            get() = maxSpeed
        override val noLimitView: ImageView
            get() = noLimit
        override val shadowBarLayout: ShadowBarLayout?
            get() = shadowBar
        override val leftContainer: ViewGroup
            get() = drivingViewLeftContainer
        override val routeView: RouteView
            get() = drivingViewDashboardRouteView
    
        override var hideViews: Boolean
            get() = super.hideViews
            set(value) {}
    }

abstract class BaseDrivingModeView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    @LayoutRes layout: Int,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : NightmodeRelativeLayout(context, attrs), (SpeedManager.Result) -> Unit {
 init {
        View.inflate(context, layout, this)
        setupView()
    }
}
```

Which is used in our dashboard fragment with layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dashboardNightmodeWhiteTint_to_fmblack">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullToRefreshFragmentDashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reportsTabLayout">

        <nl.example.views.SmileyView
            android:id="@+id/smileyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <nl.example.features.hud.views.custom.HUDHintView
        android:id="@+id/hintHUDDashboardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/drivingModeDashboardView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <nl.example.views.DrivingModeDashboardView
        android:id="@+id/drivingModeDashboardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the viewpager implements the FragmentStateAdapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(manager) {

    private val fragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val fragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
        fragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    fun clearFragments() {
        fragmentList.clear()
        fragmentTitleList.clear()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragmentList.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = fragmentList[position]
}
```

with:

```
viewPager.apply {
            offscreenPageLimit = 3
            adapter = viewPagerAdapter
            isUserInputEnabled = false
            registerOnPageChangeCallback(onPageChangeCallback)
        }
```

That dashboard fragment is put into a viewpager. It seems that none of the fragments inside that viewpager will toggle nightmode when it changes. Anyone got any idea's how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you use `context.applicationContext` instead of context itself? That way your widget only uses raw app theme and doesn't inherit activitys one.

Comment: Changed it to context. still don't work

Comment: `none of the fragments inside that viewpager will toggle nightmode when it changes` Do you change the night mode after the ViewPager loaded the fragments?; If yes, try to change the night mode before instantiating the ViewPager, and tell if that works

Comment: Nightmode should change dynamically right? And also our nightmode can change during runtime. For example when the time is going passed 6 o'clock in the evening we switch to nightmode. So the app will change runtime.